# single server installation of Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, virtual-machine, crm, dynamics-crm-4

i want to create a single server VM installation of MS Dynamics CRM.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or walkthrough on this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single server VM installation created by Microsoft. I am sure you can find it online. The problem is that it is extremely slow and very very large.

If you just want to play with Dynamics CRM, I have had better luck using  Sun's Virtual Box and building an Active Directory box, and then building a second box with CRM, and the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Good question - I often wondered myself, found this procedure, and plan to try it today:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393301.aspx

I will post my results later.  Please let me know your experience.